# Use pulley from old water pump?

Tags: mitsubishi, water-pump, pulley, lancer

The water pump on my car went out so I need a new one. The pulley itself looks fine, not bent, but the entire pulley is tilted in such a way that I'm guessing the pump shaft broke. The local part stores carry new pumps but none carry the actual pulley. Can I use the pulley from the old pump or do I need to order a new pulley online?

2004 Mitsubishi Lancer Ralliart
2.4L 4G69 MIVEC
166,000 Miles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this looks like your water pump, then yes you can:

[image: Image Pulled From RockAuto.com]

The tilt in the pulley is caused not from a broke shaft, but from a worn bushing which the shaft rides upon. This is just one of the symptoms which shows up when the pump is dying a short miserable death. As the bushing wears out, there is created more and more space (slop) which allows the shaft to lilt more and more. The force the belt creates on the pulley will in and of itself cause the tilt of the shaft. The pulley is made to come off of the pump and be reused.

Answer (score 1):

The water pump pulley is usually bolted to the pump, and can be re-used.